# How to join input to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hi I have a little problem

I have 3 forms that send different parameters via GET to another page and i have 3 inputs outside all forms that I want to send with form that user chooses to submit.

Inputs with names one, two and three must be send with 1 of that forms.

This is my code:

```html
<input type="text" name="one">
<input type="text" name="two">
<input type="text" name="three">

<form action="process.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value"Process by name">
</form>
<form action="process.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="adress">
  <input type="submit" value"Process by address">
</form>
<form action="process.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="number">
  <input type="submit" value"Process by number">
</form>
```

All I want to is, when someone submit any form, that three inputs name="(one,two,three)" are send with rest param of form.

**EDIT**: Just 1 form is submitted!

Comment: So if I understand correct, if any form is submitted, you want to send all the forms. Am I right?

Comment: Mmmm...using just one form instead of three?

Comment: No just one form that is submitted, with intups name="one,two and three"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put everything into one form, and use a hidden type value, you can ensure that all values are passed on submit.

```html
<form action="process.php" method="get" id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="one">
  <input type="text" name="two">
  <input type="text" name="three">

  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" name="btnName" value="Process by name">
  <input type="text" name="adress">
  <input type="submit" name="btnAddress" value="Process by address">
  <input type="text" name="number">
  <input type="submit" name="btnNumber" value="Process by number">
</form>
```

Since you are submitting to a PHP page, you can check which of the buttons was pressed with the following code...

```
if (isset($_POST['btnName'])) {
    //do something with name
} else if (isset($_POST['btnAddress'])) {
    //do something with adress
} else if (isset($_POST['btnNumber'])) {
    //do something with number
}
```

Comment: The question isn't tagged with JavaScript let alone jQuery

Comment: Ok, so your solution is send all and just use parameters that i want in php script, which i determine by type. This is possible solution but question is how to join input to form. My code is more complex than this demonstration i post, but thank you.